# Retrieving a value held in all instances of an object

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, closures, iife

I am working on a Person constructor function that takes a name and age as its parameters, and trying to implement a method that retrieves all the 'Person' instances current age value and outputs the average. Here's my code...

```
var Person = (function() {
    //private state
    var inst = 1;

    function Person(name, age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            Object.defineProperty(this, "age", {
                get: function() {
                    return age;
                },
                set: function(num) {
                    age = num;
                }
            });
            Object.defineProperty(this, "_id", {
                value: inst++
            });
        }

    //Attempt to return number of instances divided by all current Person weights
    Person.prototype.aveAge = function() {

        return inst;
    };
    return Person;
}());

var jim = new Person("jim", 32);
var richard = new Person("richard", 27);
richard.age = 28;
var alfie = new Person("alfie", 42);
Person.aveAge()  //Returns TypeError: Person.aveAge is not a function
```

I have set up a variable that is shared across all instances (inst) that increments each time an another instance is created and assigns a unique id. I cannot figure out how I can get to each 'age' value of all Person instances in existence using the aveAge prototype I have added at the bottom. I am also getting a 'TypeError: Person.aveAge is not a function' when I attempt to call it to even test that variable 'inst' holds the correct number of instances. Does anybody know where I am going wrong?

Comment: First of all, `Person.aveAge()` is not on the prototype, but on the constructor itself, so `Person.prototype.aveAge = ` should be `Person.aveAge = `. Secondly, your use of get/set is unnecessary and shadows the props you set manually.

Comment: `aveAge()` is a method of your Person objects, such as `jim.aveAge()`.

Comment: Probably more like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/apgk6mhL/**

Comment: Thanks for the advice all - seems I was getting a bit confused. Much appreciated for the visuals in fiddle and code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels strange to keep ages on a person when it references people. Notice that hanging things on `__proto__` makes them available from the constructor (Person), while hanging things on `prototype` makes them available from the instance (richard). If Age is updated, it needs to be done via setAge so the PeopleTracker knows to update it's memory. Also, in my example, the average is only calculated when needed rather than each time a person wants to know what is is.

```js
        var peopleTracker = {
            _count: 0,
            _ages: [],
            averageAge: 0,
            addPerson: function (age) {
                var pt = peopleTracker;

                pt._count += 1;
                pt._ages.push(age);
                pt.getAverage();
            },
            getAverage: function () {
                var sum = 0,
                    pt = peopleTracker;

                sum = pt._ages.reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return a + b;
                });

                pt.averageAge = Math.round(sum / pt._count);
            },
            update: function (oldAge, newAge) {
                var pt = peopleTracker,
                    ages = pt._ages,
                    i = ages.indexOf(oldAge);

                ages.splice(i, 1, newAge);
                pt.getAverage();
            }
        };

        var Person = function (name, age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            peopleTracker.addPerson(age);
        };

        Person.__proto__ = { // available from the constructor
            Constructor: Person,
            setAge: function (age) {
                var oldAge = this.age;
                this.age = age;
                peopleTracker.update(oldAge, age);
            },
            aveAge: function () {
                return peopleTracker.averageAge;
            }
        };

        Person.prototype = Person.__proto__; // now also available from the instance

        var jim = new Person("Jim", 32),
            richard = new Person("Richard", 27),
            alfie = new Person("Alfie", 42);

        Person.aveAge();  // 34
        richard.aveAge(); // 34
        richard.setAge(20);
        Person.aveAge();  // 31
        richard.aveAge(); // 31
```